# GitHub Action: bash script grep match failing but works locally

Tags: bash, github-actions

I am writing a GitHub Action. When testing it, I am having a lot of trouble to get a simple bash script to work.

[The bash script](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/setup-java-sdkman/blob/main/__tests__/verify-java.sh#L11) is meant to test that the Java version installed on the machine matches a regular expression. The regular expression is an argument to the bash script (`$1`), as you can see in the [workflow descriptor](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/setup-java-sdkman/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow.yml#L44).

I forked the setup-java action which had [this script](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/__tests__/verify-java.sh#L10), and the test passes there.

### Relevant snippets

#### GitHub workflow

[Full file](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/setup-java-sdkman/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow.yml#L44)

```
    - name: Verify Java 8
      if: runner.os != 'windows'
      run: __tests__/verify-java.sh "Zulu.*1\.8\.0_265" "${{ steps.setup-java-sdkman.outputs.path }}" "${{ steps.setup-java-sdkman.outputs.version }}"
```

#### Bash script

[Full file](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/setup-java-sdkman/blob/main/__tests__/verify-java.sh)

```
java_version="$(java -version 2>&1)"
echo "Found java version: $java_version"
echo "Grepping for '$1'"
if [ -z "$(echo $java_version | grep "$1")" ]; then
  echo "::error::Unexpected version"
  exit 1
fi
```

#### Current failure

[GH Action Log](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/setup-java-sdkman/runs/1293981218?check_suite_focus=true)

```
Run __tests__/verify-java.sh "Zulu.*1\.8\.0_265" "/opt/hostedtoolcache/java-8.0.265-zulu/1.0.0/x64" "8.0.265-zulu"
Found java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.48.0.53-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_265-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.48.0.53-CA-linux64) (build 25.265-b11, mixed mode)
Grepping for 'Zulu.*1\.8\.0_265'
Error: Unexpected version
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've spent hours on this simple issue. When I run the script locally on a Mac, it works... I even started an online Linux shell to try it on Ubuntu, and it also works... so I have no idea why it fails only on GitHub Actions!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the logs `java_version` is `openjdk version "1.8.0_265"` and the grep expression is `Zulu.*1\.8\.0_265` which doesn't match

Comment: `$2` and `$3` don't seem to be used

Comment: The output is multi-line. There's 3 lines showing the output (I pasted with the line numbers between). You can see that it only logs "Grepping for ..." after 4 lines.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul they are not relevant, but you can see the full script linked in the question, which uses them later.

Comment: I removed the line numbers now, so it's clearer (I thought they were helping but clearly not).

Comment: I don't think either of these matters, but try `printf` instead of `echo`, quote the variable, and probably replace the useless `[ -z ... ]`; `if printf ''%s\n "$java_version" | grep -q "$1"; then`

Comment: Screw this! Just re-wrote the script in Java (it's a script verifying Java was installed properly!), much easier. https://github.com/renatoathaydes/setup-java-sdkman/blob/main/__tests__/VerifyJava.java

Comment: grep returns with an exit code 1, if there is no match. GitHub Actions stops executing a script if any command returns a non-zero exit code. But I am not sure how to bypass this

Answer (score 2):

### Elaboration on the @smootherbug comment:

grep returns with an exit code 1, if there is no match.
GitHub Actions stops executing a script if any command returns a non-zero exit code.

To uderstand grep behavior, try this in your coommand line (linux bash):

```bash
$ echo "a" | grep b
$ echo $?
1
```

### how to bypass this?

```bash
java_version="$(java -version 2>&1)"
echo "Found java version: $java_version"
echo "Grepping for '$1'"
echo "$java_version" | grep -q "$1" || echo "::error::Unexpected version" && exit 1
```

Comment: This saved my life, i was going nuts. Thank you