# Grep failing in GitHub Action, working locally

Tags: github, github-actions

The output of `aws cloudformation list-stack-instances --stack-set-name ${{ matrix.stack }} --query 'Summaries[*].Account'` is like:

```
[
  "12345",
  "62135",
  "84328"
]
```

I'm interested in the account IDs, so actually the full command is `aws cloudformation list-stack-instances --stack-set-name ${{ matrix.stack }} --query 'Summaries[*].Account' | grep -E "\d+" | tr -d '", '`.

This just works locally. However, it was returning an empty response in GitHub Action.

After further debugging, I found out that the reason is that the `grep` is failing in GHA, and I don't have any clue why.

Basically, `aws cloudformation list-stack-instances --stack-set-name ${{ matrix.stack }} --query 'Summaries[*].Account'` returns the expected output as the example above. But then `| grep -E "\d+"` exits with an error.

Full log of the step:

```
Run $(aws cloudformation list-stack-instances --stack-set-name foo --query 'Summaries[*].Account' | grep -E "\d+")
  aws cloudformation list-stack-instances --stack-set-name foo --query 'Summaries[*].Account' | grep -E "\d+"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: eu-west-1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Any ideas?

Found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487952/github-action-bash-script-grep-match-failing-but-works-locally) with no answer.

EDIT:

For now, I managed to workaround this by also passing `[]` to the `tr`, but I'm leaving the question open because I'm quite curious about why the hell `grep` is not working.

Answer (score 6):

I spent countless hours on this myself. You will have to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much, I have also wasted hours wondering what wasn't working with grep, and this was it.  Not sure why \d isn't liked sometimes.